# PATH_INFO não mostra barras "extras"

Tags: php, url, path

Estou usando o `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` para passar valores para o backend através da url, sem ser no formato `?chave=valor`, em vez disso, `/:valor/` (identifico o dois pontos e retorno uma variável com aquele nome), porém, quando tenho uma requisição para a url `//valor/` o valor de `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` é `/valor/`, causando uns problemas...

Por que? E como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema usando `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` e `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`:

```
//Requisição para example.com/index.php/foo//bar/baz
$current_route = str_replace("/", "\/", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]); // \/index.php"
$current_route = preg_replace("/(\.[a-z]*)/", "($1)?", $current_route); // \/index(.php)?
$current_route = preg_replace("/{$current_route}/", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); // /foo//bar/baz
```

A segunda linha torna opcional a extenção `.php` porque escondi o mesmo pelo `.htaccess`

Comment: Não use `preg_replace` assim `{$current_route}`, use `preg_quote`, ou melhor, neste caso nem precisaria de preg_replace.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento complementei a resposta, talvez tenha ficado mais claro, mas se achar que está errado mesmo assim, poderia me explicar melhor? Qual o problema de `{$current_route}`?

Comment: O problema é misturar string com expressão regular, mas no geral o ultimo preg_replace poderia ser trocado por substr contando os caracteres de $current_route, pq ai nem precisaria de preg_quote para evitar a URL quebrar a regex. Da forma que esta teu código simplesmente vai quebrar se alguém digitar uma URL como `/[a-z]/` manualmente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento testei com `[a-z]` e até com `.*` no meio da URL e continuou funcionando, acho que não da pra usar o `substr` dessa vez por causa da extensão `.php` opcional

Comment: Já deixei avisado, misturar regex com string pode dar problema, para evitar use simplesmente `preg_quote` para escapar metacaracteres, a sugestão do substr era para simplificar, mas o preg_replace e preg_quote mesmo que fique mais código já resolve o problema todo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como ficaria? Tentei aqui, sem sucesso